# Windows Application Packaging Project Trying to Package Two of Same File Causing Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, appx

I have created a [Windows Application Packaging Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) in Visual Studio to package a UWP Application and a Console Application together. Everything in the project compiles just fine, and I am able to create an AppPackage for the UWP application by itself.

However, when I attempt to make an AppPackage for the `Windows Application Packaging Project` I get the following error:

> You can't add both "C:\Users\jhogle.nuget\packages\acr.userdialogs\7.0.1\lib\uap10.0.16299\Acr.UserDialogs\Platforms\Uwp\ActionSheetContentDialog.xaml" and "C:\Users\jhogle\Documents\Git\sMARt\Client\Client.UWP\bin\x86\Release\ilc\Acr.UserDialogs\Platforms\Uwp\ActionSheetContentDialog.xaml" to the output file as "Acr.UserDialogs\Platforms\Uwp\ActionSheetContentDialog.xaml"

I know that `Arc.UserDialogs` is a nuget package that I am using in the UWP application.  However, I don't understand what is causing this file to be added twice.

The UWP app is the only project in the solution that references `Arc.UserDialogs`. It seems to be trying to add the file in question from both the nuget install location, and the output of the UWP application.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:**

As per Sunteen Wu's comment, I am adding the contents of `ActionSheetContentDialog.xaml` They can be found [here.](https://pastebin.com/TkSxKMqm)

Comment: `C:\Users\jhogle\Documents\Git` What's this folder for? Did you use `Git` for managing your code snippet? And just for ensure,  you're using [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs/), right?

Comment: That is the folder that the project is stored in with "sMARt" being the name of the project. Yes, that is the package I am using.

Comment: Please show the relative code snippet in `ActionSheetContentDialog.xaml` that  using the package relative APIs  to help us reproduce your project on our side.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT I have included the file in the post. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your issue. Without a reproduce project I cannot help more since your issue should be happened special with your project. Try to create a blank app to add several simple pages for testing.